# Run jquery functions if file is uploaded or not

Tags: jquery, file, input, height, field

I'm attempting to change the height of a div dependent upon if a file is currently submitted or not in an input.

My input has an id="upload"

As of now I'm running this function using .change:

```
$('#upload').change(function(){
   $('div').css("height", "1000px");
});
```

This works perfectly when I upload the file, but then when I remove the file, the input is being changed again so the height of the div remains the same. So, I need a solution that is reversible and works both ways. I've tried several other functions where I check the value, as well as the length of the input, but I can't seem to get anything that works.

Comment: Are you just wanting to `grow` when there is a file and `shrink` when there is no file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you're saying, I think this should work for you. It checks the length of the value of the #upload element after a change, and if it's not bigger than 0 (thus empty), it scales the div element back to 50 px (boldly assuming that that is it's original size).

```
$('#upload').change(function() {
  if (jQuery(this).val().length > 0) {
    $('div').css("height", "1000px");
  } else {
    $('div').css("height", "50px");
  }
});
```

I've put it in a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/7b0hvo3u/

It's also possible to first retrieve the original height of the div element, store that somewhere, and use that instead of the hard-coded "50px".
That would make it look like this:

```
var originalHeight;
$('document').ready(function() {
  originalHeight = $('div').height();
});
$('#upload').change(function() {
  if (jQuery(this).val().length > 0) {
    $('div').css("height", "1000px");
  } else {
    $('div').css("height", originalHeight);
  }
});
```

A fiddle for this variation is here: https://jsfiddle.net/ywsthj2p/1/

Hope this helps somewhat, if not: please elaborate :)